# overwritten git repo with old version of git repo, game over?

Tags: git, backup, recovery, data-recovery

Have I totally lost all my commits? I know it was dumb, and for that I am sorry, but it was an innocent mistake, not thinking a workflow through properly.

**EDIT**

the overwrite was a manual drag and drop, no terminal commands entered.

I am on a mac.

I have time machine, and can retrieve my old new repo (if you know what I mean, my head is melting), but can I merge them (have have since made changes, deadline looking) or should I just reinstate the backup in it's entirety?

Comment: What exactly did you do?  Do you have clones elsewhere?

Comment: no clones!! I overwrote the folder with an older folder! Now my head is sore (the brick wall seems fine)

Comment: Can you list the exact commands you ran, where you cloned the repo from etc. in detail. As it stands, this question is hopelessly vague.

Comment: before anything else, save what you have, whatever left you have. Then explain exactly what you did

Comment: Files wise, I still have everything (phew) I have just lost commits.

Comment: Not sure there was any need for a down vote. Some people, eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it will be cumbersome, but your commits will probably still be there …

run `git fsck --full` (might take a while) – it will list all dangling blobs/trees/commits. inspect each danging commit with `git log`/`git show`/`gitk`. when you find a head commit of a branch, recreate the branch with `git branch <branchname> <sha1 of commit>` (you have to remember your old branch names)

---

since you recovered your old repository state using time machine and have your old repository now on your desktop, simplest thing to do for you would be adding a new remote and then fetching the remote commits:

```
git remote add old-repo /path/to/your/desktop/old-dir/.git
# sorry, no clue what the actual path might be on mac systems (~/Desktop/…?)
git fetch old-repo
```

after that you will have all branches from your old repository available as `old-repo/branchname`. to merge them simply issue a `git merge old-repo/branch` command. this is mere basic git fu to set up a repository as an additional remote and merge its changes (no magic going on here, move along)

Comment: if you're asking about merging the two: yes, you can merge them. they will have a common ancester which can be used as a merge based. remember: git identifies commits with their hash, so the exact same commit will have the exact same hash. everywhere. everytime.

Comment: what is the process of doing this?

Comment: first, find your old commits. secondly, run `git merge <branch or commit to be merged>`. there's no way around finding your old commits. you could however copy the current (new) state of your repository elsewhere, revert the original repository path to its old state and then pull the changes from your copied repository

Comment: I have my old commits, but they are now sat in a different folder on my desktop, how do I pull them all together without overwritting it again?

Comment: @mild fuzz: i've updated my answer to explain merging of another repository (which is not already a remote)

Answer (score 1):

Windows ? Linux ?

If its Windows you can *attempt* recovering your files using recovery tools or a hex editor that can directly read the disk. On Linux, I don't know.

But yeah if you have no backups... it's your fault ! =)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, just sometimes you can be lucky. On windows 7, open the properties of the folder and click "Previous Versions".

I was lucky enough to find an old iPhone backup using that technique when it looked like i'd lost all!!